# Andengine text indexoutofbounds exception

Tags: android, andengine

i am programming a game with andengine and i am using Andengine Text to display the high score...

Thats the code:

```
StrokeFont mFont = FontFactory.createStrokeFromAsset(this.getFontManager(), mainFontTexture, this.getAssets(), "Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf", 100, true, Color.WHITE, 2, Color.BLACK);
mFont.load();

text_score_menu = new Text(25, 25, mFont, "Score: ",getVertexBufferObjectManager());


if(LC.Score>Constants.highScore){
     prefs.edit().putInt("highScore",LC.Score).commit();
     text_score_menu.setText("New High: " + LC.Score);
}else{
     text_score_menu.setText("Score: " + LC.Score);
}
```

Problem is that when there is new high score i am getting a new exception exactly here:

```
text_score_menu.setText("New High: " + LC.Score);
```

but i dont have that problem when the score is not new highscore and score is display with

```
text_score_menu.setText("Score: " + LC.Score);
```

here is the error message:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: UpdateThread
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=210; index=210
            at org.andengine.entity.text.vbo.HighPerformanceTextVertexBufferObject.onUpdateVertices(HighPerformanceTextVertexBufferObject.java:121)
            at org.andengine.entity.text.Text.onUpdateVertices(Text.java:335)
            at org.andengine.entity.text.Text.setText(Text.java:223)
```

Comment: length is 210. index starts from 0. So the array does not have a element @ index 210.

Comment: That i know... but i have nothing to do with length. I am simply trying to display a text "New High: 8". Its not 210 characters

Comment: but your stacktrace is suggesting what i just mentioned. What is `LC.Score`?

Comment: LC.Score is the current score and its an integer maximum 2 digits

Comment: OK i found the answer myself...

Its something to do with initialization. 

here how i initialize text. "Score: "

so max characters are defined here somehow and when i try to display "New High: 8" its too long.

Instead i did initialization different ( with lots of empty spaces)
"Score:........."
and it worked like charm :) Sorry i am not familiar with comment formating

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this is a common pitfall with text in AndEngine - when you instantiated the text_score_menu entity, you set the max length then. Try changing this

`text_score_menu = new Text(25, 25, mFont, "Score: ",getVertexBufferObjectManager());`

to

`text_score_menu = new Text(25, 25, mFont, "New High: 123456789",getVertexBufferObjectManager());`

that will establish a long enough text field - then be sure to "set" the proper text before showing the entity - (as you are doing in the code you presented)

Comment: we found the answer at the same time.. Thanks anyway :)